# log4cxx error on node shutdown in diamondback rc3

Tags: ros, logger, log4cxx, ros-diamondback

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I installed diamondback RC3 yesterday on a machine that was *upgraded* from Ubuntu 9.04 to 10.04 over the weekend. *(Maybe upgrading instead of a fresh install was a bad idea?)*

log4cxx seems to be having a problem. Every time I ctrl+c a launch file that I ran, I get an error that looks like this:

```
log4cxx: No appender could be found for logger (ros.sbpl_arm_planner).
log4cxx: Please initialize the log4cxx system properly.
```

or

```
log4cxx: No appender could be found for logger (ros.planning_environment).
log4cxx: Please initialize the log4cxx system properly.
```

Is log4cxx set up incorrectly? Has anyone seen this before?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9225/log4cxx-error-on-node-shutdown-in-diamondback-rc3/) by [ben](https://answers.ros.org/users/33/ben/) on ROS Answers with karma: 674 on 2011-02-27

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is a known problem with Diamondback RC3. There is a [ticket](https://code.ros.org/trac/ros/ticket/3375) on the ROS Trac for this.

---

Originally posted by [Eric Perko](https://answers.ros.org/users/14/eric-perko/) with karma: 8406 on 2011-02-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3